# LaTeX footnote markers at beginning of word could benefit from kerning?

Tags: latex, kerning, footnotes

I'm using the *manyfoot* package in LaTeX to create a footnote apparatus. My question is about footnote markers that appear in the main body of the text (not about the footnotes as they appear in the apparatus).

The person I'm formatting this document for actually wants the main body footnote markers to appear *before* various words, not after, as you'd usually see. There's no problem doing this, but I'm seeing a particular effect I don't like with certain letters that begin some words. Here's an example so you can see what I'm talking about:

[image: image showing too much space between marker and sloping capital letter]

When the opening letter slopes, there seems to be too much space between the letter and the footnote marker. For comparison, here's a marker that comes before a non-sloping letter that looks nice:

[image]

So my question is this: Is there a way to introduce kerning or some sort of elastic spacing that would move the footnote marker closer to the opening letter of the word if the opening letter slopes? I think that would improve the look considerably.